# Generate HTML within bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, include

I have downloaded a bootstrap template for a website, and Im trying to learn how it all works.   Looks good so far, but the template I have downloaded has much of the same content across the 5 main pages, and it is not generated or referred to from a single place.   Since the navbar is the same across all the webpages, how could I refer all of the pages to include the same header (or other html), without a server side?  This seems like a simple HTML or JS solution, just can't seem to find what I'm looking for....

Lets say this is the navbar (saved as `/component/navbar.html` ¿maybe?):

```
<div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="brand" href="index.html">
                    <b>Your</b>Site
                </a>
                <div class="nav-collapse fr">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="work.html">Our work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
                        <!-- <li><a href="plans.html">Pricing</a></li> -->
                        <li><a href="explore.html">Explore</a></li>
                        <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="alt.html">Alt</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><button class="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div><!-- end .container -->
        </div><!-- end .navbar-inner -->
    </div><!-- end .navbar -->
```

How do I link the pages to this piece of HTML to be included?

Comment: That is not possible with html, you should use php or an other backend language to do that. Javascript is not an option because you want people without js to also see the menu.

Comment: If people not have javascript enabled, most of bootstrap is useless anyway - like the above used `collapse`.

Comment: agreed,   with the proliferation of JS, I am willing to force people to use it, esp given the content of the site is just content, no login, no security aspects,  I'm just trying to make the site and the experience more enjoyable.

Comment: I think it is "old-school" even to consider anyone would have javascript disabled. It was in the 90'ties that could theoretically happend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery, always present in boostrap.

Port the content inside `<div class="navbar">` to a file as you suggest called `/component/navbar.html` - so the HTML looks like this

```
<div class="navbar" id="navbar"> 
</div>
```

in a script, load the content from `navbar.html` into `#navbar` via AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : 'component/navbar.html',
        success(html) {
            $("#navbar").html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit** : or simply `$("#navbar").load('component/navbar.html');` 
This is maybe the solution you are looking for, it behaves more like a kind of "include" you can place in the headers.

Comment: I keep getting the error: `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.   I've tried looking into this, and getting different directions.   Any ideas?

Comment: found it.  First close ALL of Chrome (since this is the main issue), then from the terminal, open it with the special parameter using this `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files`

Comment: it should not be a "runtime" problem. However, i can only guess why normal code loaded by load() should be a problem, and why you want it. The reason Google does this intensively is not that it is smart, but that it is the only way they can do all their callbacks)